# Magento Proxy Error 502 error reading from remote server

Tags: performance, magento, proxy, e-commerce, webshop

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2mzgzso&s=6

Hi Stacks,

I face several problems on my magento site. When im in the backend and add new products is got 502 proxy errors, and even when im at the site self i do face proxy errors. Very frustrating. My host couldn't help me.

We are using ezapp full page cache due to if we don't use cache the whole site is under proxy errors.

Do anybody know where this problem is come from?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to reproduce your error from the other place (other internet provider) to be sure that error is on the host side.

Comment: Ok have you exp. it before on magento? Any tips on speed it up?

Comment: Never before. I think it's not a Magento problem. Something wrong with connection request flow.

Comment: What do you suggest for hosting?
More CPU or RAM?

Comment: I don't think it will solve your problem :) First of all you should try my first suggestion.

Comment: Ok, i think its caused by the cache.
http://bit.ly/iefbw1
This is the website where we talking about.